# Rate of water flow in a given container

Tags: volume

[image]

The containers  in the picture has height h cm . Their other dimensions are shown . The containers are being filled to the brim with water which flows into each one at the same constant rate . It takes 5mins for the water to reach a depth of $h/2$ cm in container A

Find the time take for water to reach he Brim of container B.

I'm not sure how to interpret this because time taken to fill the cone and cylinder respectively is different .

I do know how to find the time taken to fill container A (8x5) but I'm not too sure how to do it for container B ...

Can I get a hint or help. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

I'd point out sketch solution, do comment if you still don't get it

The rate of water flowing into each container is constant (it's the same for the two containers but you don't know what the rate is yet).

You are given the information that it took $5$ minutes to fill the container $A$ to the height $h/2$ - **this information tells you what the constant rate is**.

Once you find the constant rate all you have to do is find the volume of container $B$ and divide it by the rate at which water flows in